# Ethminer pool mining success log

Tags: ethminer

What do the ethminer logs look like when you have successfully mined something as part of a pool. Say on ethermine.org?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
 04:29:49.568|ethminer Solution found; Submitting to ...
              Submitted and accepted
```